# Can't access EntityManager with JPA 2.1 and Hibernate5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have an application with Hibernate 5, and added JPA 2.1 to perform bulk Updates with CriteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate().

But I need to assign CriteriaBuilder from EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(), and I can't get the EntityManager.

I don't have a persistence.xml file, and I thought Hibernate would provide an EntityManager for me.

I tried the following annotations in the DAO class:

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager
```

and

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

Both fail to inject the dependency.
I also tried to instace an EntityManagerFactory, but it failed as I don't have a persistence.xml file. All the entities are annotated like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "My_Entity")
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8442071276091708080L;

 @Column(name = "VALUE", nullable = false)
 private BigDecimal value;

...
}
```

Here is part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Hibernate instances the SessionFactory, is there a way to get the EM from it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring it would be much easier to use the spring boot starters modules. For JPA it would be "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" you can find the definition of the maven dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa).

Additionally, could you add more information about your configuration? You say you don't use a persistence.xml so what do you use to set your datasources?

Comment: Question updated. I do use Spring, but not Spring Boot, maybe I can just add that package you mentioned? I use only annotations, to map data.

Comment: Do you also define the beans sessionFactory somewhere? What about the datasource declaration? Was you app working before using JPA?

Comment: oops didn't mean to commit that message before, it was not done.

Comment: grmbl no edit >< anyway, on my app I use java conf to set the datasource, entityManager and transaction manager. Have a look at http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa to have an exemple of how to do it.